# ssh time restrictions after ubuntu upgrade

Tags: upgrade, ssh

I have recently upgraded our lab server from ubuntu version 18.04 to version 20.04. Since the upgrade, ~15 minutes after restarting the server, ssh stops working; any users already logged in have their sessions terminated (regardless of whether they are active or not), and anyone trying to ssh in receives an operation timed out error. If the server is rebooted, ssh works perfectly fine for ~15 minutes before the same problems occur.

I'm guessing I probably need to change something in the ssh_config file, but I'm not sure what. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Would you check and share the log: `journalctl --unit=ssh` from the server side, also if the service is up after ~15min: `sudo systemctl status sshd.service`  and `sudo ss -ltupn`

Comment: Thank you, this has solved the problem! Realised the system was going to sleep  - I'd previously been concentrating on settings in sshd_config, so was looking in the wrong place. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nice kathryn, you are welcome. You should be able to flag it as accepted after 48h. https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for answering my own question, but I have now solved the problem after running the commands suggested in user.dz's comment under my question. Realised that since the upgrade the system goes to sleep afer ~15 minutes, thus preventing ssh access until it is manually woken up. Solved this by running:

`sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`